# Nuxt2: Как лучше реализовать два разных счетчика Яндекс Метрики для разынх локалей?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, i18n

Сейчас используется пакет @nuxtjs/yandex-metrika. В nuxt.config.js прописан конфиг:

```
'@nuxtjs/yandex-metrika',
  {
    id: XXXXXX,
    clickmap: true,
    trackLinks: true,
    accurateTrackBounce: true,
    webvisor: true
  }
```

Так же используется @nuxtjs/i18n с опцией differentDomains: true. Задача для разных языков инициализировать счетчик с разным id. Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Обрисуйте счетчик вручную.

Comment: Да, похоже так и придется. С vue не особо дружу, правильно понимаю, что будте правильно в layout вставить инициалзиацию счтчика, в хук mounted()?

Comment: в итоге решил сделать через свой plugin, скопировал туда часть логики из пакета яндекс метрики и проверку на локаль